# can't send Auth data to other domain in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

im working on 2 projects with a single login, so if i already logined in `www.domain1.com`, automatically i loginned in `www.domain2.com` too with a same auth data. But now when i already login in `www.domain1.com`, the auth data didn't sent to `www.domain2.com`. im using Session to share the auth data, but still didn't work. this is what i did so far. (the projects still in localhost)

www.domain1.com login (Controller)

```
public function dologin(Request $r)
  {
    $credentials = array(
      'username' => $r->username,
      'password' => $r->password
    );
    if (\Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
      return view('setcookie');
    }
    else {
      return redirect()->to('/')->withErrors('Username or Password Incorrect !');
    }
  }
```

setcookie.blade.php

```
<body>
  <img src="http://localhost:8000/app_task/public/setcookie?id={{ Session::getId() }}" style="display:none;" />
</body>
```

www.domain2.com setcookie

```
Route::get('setcookie', function(){
  Session::setId($_GET['id']);
  Session::start();
  return 'Cookie created';
});
```

i can get the session id in the log (on domain 2), but when i trying to get \Auth::user()->id (in domain2), i got the Trying to get property of non-object error, that means the user id that loginned in domain1 didn't shared to domain2 (and other auth data such as username etc). Please help me to explain why i got this problem and give me a solution to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Does Domain1 and Domain 2 share the same database for authenticating users?

Comment: yes it does, i aleady get the solution for this problem by using database session driver instead of file driver, im using the same session table for both domain so it can get the same authenticated user_id if i set session id of domain1 inside domain2.. thanks for your response.. @Azeame

Comment: That's great, you should post your solution as the answer your own question so that the next person knows how to resolve this. @janotama

Comment: already post my answer.. thank you.. @Azeame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i aleady get the solution for this problem by using `database session driver` instead of `file session driver`, im using the same session table for both domain so it can get the same authenticated `user_id` if i set `session id` of `domain1` inside `domain2`. For create session table, im using the laravel official site https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#driver-prerequisites
guide.